# Access Web Datasheet in a webApp

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to write a web application in C# ASP.NET 3.5 and want to include a Microsoft Office Access Web Datasheet in my application. I can't find an example on how to use it anywhere.

It's the editing view in a SharePoint grid so I know it's possible, I just can't find out how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking us to find examples for you or do you have a concrete programming problem? Why does an out-of-the-box-gridview not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, I believe this is not possible. This similar [question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_24539090.html) seems to confirm this. However, there are many alternatives for this to do.

Lately, I have been working with Telerik controls a lot, which creates great results. Many free alternatives are also available for several development frameworks, so why don't you look into this first?

Comment: Could you name some of the free alternatives?

Comment: There are a few jQuery table plugins listed here: sitepoint.com/30-amazing-jquery-tables. I found this plugin called Handsontable very interesting that I'm gonna try out myself: http://handsontable.com/.

Comment: I also found this article on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622716/choosing-a-jquery-datagrid-plugin. I think this should provide you enough information?