# Choosing a jQuery datagrid plugin?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a dynamic datagrid in my web application and since I am using jQuery I am eager to use the plugins available. I am not aware of most of them and also require good documentation because I am new to this, and it will be difficult for me to start without documentation. Where is the the documentation and which site should I look to for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a good datagrid plug-in for jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685664/looking-for-a-good-datagrid-plug-in-for-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Grid Recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)

Comment: A good one with php and mysql integration is openjs grid.  http://square-bracket.com/openjs

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

**Update**

The link above takes to a question that was closed and then deleted. Here are the original suggestions that were on the most voted answer:

- **Gijgo Grid:** http://gijgo.com/grid/
- **jQuery Grid:** http://www.trirand.com/blog/
- **Ingrid:** http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/
- **SlickGrid** http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid
- **DataTables** http://www.datatables.net/
- **ShieldUI Grid** http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage

Comment: @think123 Not actually broken, the question, for some reason, got closed and then deleted. Users with higher rep can still see it.

Comment: YUI datatable is good I use both 2.x and I am starting to use 3.x

Comment: wondering if anybody ever noticed [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) is out there

Comment: That page is another casualty of the overzealous moderating that is plaguing SO...

Comment: I think that you will be fascinated if you check the [shieldui grid widget](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage)

Comment: Is this [`jeasyUI`](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php) recommended for standard application development? Without much thinking I used a code and spent much time developing a full application on it realize that's it's heavily dependent of jeasyUI's datagrid. What could be a standard plugin to replace this one without much changes to the code/flow?

Comment: Datatables worked extremely well for my last project. Great documentation too!

Comment: SlickGrid seems to be inactive since 2014

Comment: jQuery Bootgrid can be a nice option (if you use bootstrap) => http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

Comment: I am using ShieldUI grid and it provides a rich variety of features.https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage

Comment: jquery grid by gijgo.com is also a very good option, especially when you are using Bootstrap. http://gijgo.com/grid

Answer (score 13):

A good plugin that I have used before is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net).

Comment: Agreed. DataTables has a lot of functionality and has pretty good documentation

Comment: This is the best in my experience

Comment: I wish datatables had a nested grid option.... expandable rows to show sub grids

Answer (score 9):

The three most used and well supported jQuery grid plugins today are [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki), [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). See http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Grid-OtherGrids for more info.

Comment: Please keep in mind that slickgrid still does not have Jquery 1.9 support.

Comment: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/