# Kendo UI Grid alternative

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any free / open source alternative to the Kendo UI Grid?

I used to use their Grid module when it was included in the free version, now it isn't anymore and, as I only need the Grid module, it is too expensive for me.

Comment: Maybe this thread might be of any help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622716/choosing-a-jquery-datagrid-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know is this even alternative for Kendo UI grid but jQuery DataTables plugin is one https://www.datatables.net

It does have paging, sorting, supports almost every datasource and can be themed by Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery UI etc.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of libraries but I introduce some of them

[zinoUI](http://zinoui.com/)

[jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/)

[jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/)

[Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/)

a source for Pros and Cons is : [Top 5 jQuery UI Alternatives](https://www.sitepoint.com/top-5-jquery-ui-alternatives/)

All of the above libraries are  modular so you can only use the grid.

Comment: jQuery EasyUI = best ever!
How do I give 100 up votes to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ag Grid is one of the best ones I stumbled upon. Using in production since last year.
https://www.ag-grid.com/